# Order of execution for JS Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In the following I am trying to load a div and then display the contents as a bootstrap modal popup. Unfortunately the order of execution doesn't work and it is confusing me. Anyone have any ideas?

```
function showRealSpadTable(realSpadDetails) {
    var tableDetails = realSpadDetails;


    $.post("realSpadTable.php", {
        tableDetails: tableDetails
    }, function(data) {

    })

    $("#myModal").load("realSpadModal.php", function() {
        alert("load was performed")
    });

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: are you trying to display the result of the ajax call in your modal?

Comment: Personally, I find this question to be too vague to answer. Specifically, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I should elaborate - I am loading the contents of a modal popup into a div called myModal, then I try to display the modal with the .modal('show') command. Unfortunately it tries to run the .show command before it lods the div. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes Tjaart that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have also tried this way:$.ajax({
        url:  'realSpadModal.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(){$('#myModal').modal('show')},
        error: function(){alert("error")}});

Answer (score 0):

Show your modal inside the callback of the load function. Callbacks run asynchronously.

```
$("#myModal").load("realSpadModal.php", function() {
    alert("load was performed");
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

The modal will now always show after you alert.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion and the code alerts "load was performed" but the php file is not actually loaded into the div and the modal has nothing to display.

Comment: ok It seems I had a syntax error in the div. The modal pops up now.